# AppContainer not available for Windows 10 Chrome (no Metro mode)

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, modern-ui

I can't believe a simple Google search has only 2 relevant results:
http://www.tenforums.com/browsers-email/4810-chrome-will-not-launch-when-windows-8-mode-selected.html
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=470227

The first link gave us a registry fix, but that doesn't really change anything. The only time I see the option to restart in "Windows 8 Mode" is by changing compatibility mode of Chrome to Windows 8.

That unfortunately doesn't work either, and only results in unresponsive Chrome continuously running in the background. I am especially interested in the second link though, and ask whether there is an update to that so-called "fix"?

The reason I want to try Metro Mode is for mostly curiosity, and a bit of extra security (I guess). I don't use any third-party plugins not built-in/sandboxed with Chrome.

Comment: Sorry for double-posting, but I need to add more links:
http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/chrome-sandboxed.377440/page-11#post-2509773
http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/chrome-sandboxed.377440/page-13#post-2510499

Comment: Somehow missed this, guess it's gone...: https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/chrome/JhEu4oTQYkk

Answer (score 1):

OK, since this is still somehow a top Google search result with no answers, I will provide the answer here.

Although it's a Twitter post of all things, that is actually the only official result I can find via Google at this moment: https://twitter.com/tiraniddo/status/692485455208660995

[image]
<sup>**Enable AppContainer Lockdown**</sup>